# Cesiumjs zoom to mouse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, zooming, cesiumjs

We use Cesiumjs map in our project. 
When we try to zoom it zooms to the center of the screen, instead of to the mouse location.

Does anyone knows how to fix it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented in Cesium 1.11 released on 1 July 2015 ([release blog post](https://cesiumjs.org/2015/07/01/Cesium-version-1.11-released/), [pull request](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/2810)).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not implemented yet.  It's on the [Camera Roadmap](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/1060) as [issue #302](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/302).